# How to textFile to avoid "Out of Heap Space"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data as following in a text file

AAAA 0000 0.548 1.008 15.994

AAAB 0001 0.654 4.543 12.994

AAAB 0001 0.126 2.222 14.954

(~300K lines)

I collected the data into an array as follows

```
       val logData = sc.textFile("data.txt",2).collect
```

Now I want to multiply all the 3rd fields and 5th fields and store them in another array, like this

0.548*15.994

0.654*12.994

so on

and store the output in a separate array.For that I used

```
       val arr = logData.map(item => item(2).toFloat*item(4).toFloat)
```

It gives me Out of Heap Space error no matter how much I increase the heap size.

Is it good to code the above way or is there any other effiecient way

Comment: Well since you're running out of memory whilst reading the entire file into memory before doing any operations on them, I first thing to look at would be not to read the entire file into memory. You could investigate I/O streaming from files or something similar.

Comment: @MichaelKendra, i think there's more going on here than the OP has described. 300K lines is tiny for a modern computer. But streaming is still a good idea if the files are in fact larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a variant you could do:

```
val arr:Array[Float] = Source
  .fromFile("data.txt")
  .getLines()
  .map(
    line => {
      val split = line.split(" ")
      split(2).toFloat * split(4).toFloat
    }
  ).toArray
```

I've run to run this code on file with 300k lines without any memory tweaks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `collect` when `textFile` so it's not the driver's "job", but executor's to calculate the result.

With `collect` you effectively load the entire file to the driver's memory that probably started with a mere 1G.